# Python, Variable not passing in String

Tags: python

I am trying to pass some variables into my string.  However when I run this, i literally get `userid` and `monthyear`

code:
`url = (r"C:\Users\{userid}\Report - {monthyear}.xlsx")`

Returns:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\{userid}\\Report - {monthyear}.xlsx'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal)

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the f for formatting

```
url = (rf"C:\Users\{userid}\Report - {monthyear}.xlsx")
```